# Get Capture Group and Line before Match using Grep

Tags: regex, linux, perl, grep

Suppose I have a file called `'test.txt'`:

```
>reference1
fooHappybar
>reference2
fooBirthdaybar
```

I need a grep command that will capture the string between `foo` and `bar`, and the line directly above the match. The command should result in the following output:

```
>reference1
Happy
>reference2
Birthday
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
grep -oP 'foo\K\w+(?=bar)' test.txt
```

which gives:

```
Happy
Birthday
```

I know that `grep -B 1` outputs the match and line before the match. I tried:

```
grep -oP -B 1 'foo\K\w+(?=bar)' test.txt
```

But that doesn't work.

Any guidance is appreciated.

EDIT:

How would the `awk` command change if I had this file instead?

```
>reference1
AGTCTGCAFOOHAPPYBARGTACAC
>reference2
GTACAFOOBIRTHDAYBARGACCAT
```

expected output:

```
>reference1
HAPPY
>reference2
BIRTHDAY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk '/FOO.+BAR/{gsub(/.*FOO|BAR.*/, ""); print p ORS $0} {p=$0}' file
```

```
>reference1
HAPPY
>reference2
BIRTHDAY
```

Comment: The `awk` command you showed me works for the example but my file is actually more complicated. I added a follow up question in the EDIT. Can you take a look?

Comment: added. I tried to give an simple example close to my actual file

Comment: @cooldood3490 - you'd just have to change capitalisation and remove the anchors `^` and `$` from the regex. (replace them w/ `.*`)

Comment: @cooldood3490: Sorry I had to step away for some work. Answer updated.

Answer (score 5):

Grep solution

```
grep -zPo '(foo)\K(\w+(?=bar))|.*(?=\n(?1)(?2))' | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Perl solution

```
perl -nE '/^foo(.*)bar$/&&say$p.$1;$p=$_'
```

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid this is impossible only using grep.
The reason is, that -o disables -B.

> Print NUM lines of leading context before matching lines. Places a line containing a group separator (--) between contiguous groups of matches. With the -o or --only-matching option, this has no effect and a warning is given.